# How to find first occurance of whitespace(tab+space+etc) in java?

Tags: java

So I have something like this

```
System.out.println(some_string.indexOf("\\s+"));
```

this gives me -1

but when I do with specific value like \t or space

```
System.out.println(some_string.indexOf("\t"));
```

I get the correct index.

Is there any way I can get the index of the first occurrence of whitespace without using split, as my string is very long.

PS - if it helps, here is my requirement. I want the first number in the string which is separated from the rest of the string by a tab or space ,and i am trying to avoid split("\\s+")[0]. The string starts with that number and has a space or tab after the number ends

Comment: `indexOf` [doesn't](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) take a regex as an argument

Comment: The number - separated just on the left or also on the right?

Comment: the string starts with that number and has a space or tab after the number ends

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is: indexOf() takes a **char**, or a string; but **not** a regular expression.

Thus:

```
String input = "a\tb";
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(input.indexOf('\t'));
```

prints 1 because there is a TAB char at index 1.

```
System.out.println(input.indexOf("\\s+"));
```

prints -1 because there is no substring `\\s+` in your input value.

In other words: if you want to use the powers of regular expressions, you can't use indexOf(). You would be rather looking towards [String.match()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) for example. But of course - that gives a boolean result; not an index.

If you intend to find the index of the first whitespace, you have to iterate the chars manually, like:

```
for (int index = 0; index < input.length(); index++) {
   if (Character.isWhitespace(input.charAt(index))) { 
     return index;
   }
}
return -1;
```

Comment: Funny. People were correct and quick to downvote my initially wrong answer. Lets see if those votes ever come back.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added that one thing as well.

Comment: In terms of performance, a use of `indexOf(' ')` and `indexOf('\t')` wouldn't be that bad. It's less verbose too

Answer (score 4):

Something of this sort might help? Though there are better ways to do this.

```
class Sample{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1110 001";
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ){
        if(Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Required Index : " + index);
}
}
```

Comment: Let me find out any other approach to suit your needs :-)

Comment: Aritra, you can combine Java 8 stream (`IntStream` here) with `indexOf` ;P.

Comment: Yeah @Tom thanks for the valuable suggestion. Let me check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to find with a regular expression, you'll need to use the regular expression classes.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\s");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(s);
if ( m.find() ) {
    System.out.println( "Found \\s at " + m.start());
}
```

The `find` method of the `Matcher` class locates the pattern in the string for which the matcher was created. If it succeeds, the `start()` method gives you the index of the first character of the match.

Note that you can compile the pattern only once (even create a constant). You just have to create a `Matcher` for every string.

Comment: "I want the first number in the string which is seperated from the rest of the string by a tab or space".
So actually you could define the regex like `\\s\\d+`

Comment: @Jérôme You missed the comment *the string starts with that number and has a space or tab after the number ends*. I have now edited it into the question.

Comment: True i missed it. Thx for clarification